# Bundle not using rbenv version

Tags: ruby, macos, rbenv

I'm trying to bundle using rbenv. When I check the ruby version it gives me 2.4.0, rbenv. But when calling bundle it's using the default installed osx version.

```
MacBook-Pro-256:kittens-or-puppies antarrbyrd$ bundle
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.0
MacBook-Pro-256:kittens-or-puppies antarrbyrd$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run `rbenv rehash`

> The rehash command updates the shim for the bundle binary.

Make sure you've added this to your .bash_profile

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Also try uninstalling bundler and reinstalling it, then running `rehash`.

http://dan.carley.co/blog/2012/02/07/rbenv-and-bundler/

Comment: I've already tried that

Comment: @AntarrByrd I updated the answer with more info.

Comment: reinstalling bundler did it

Comment: if you're using zshell, add this to .zshrc instead of `.bash_profile`

Comment: `echo export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)" > ~/.bash_profile`

Works